# LC3 assembly program, print instruction

Tags: assembly, printing, load, instructions, lc3

The following LC3 program will print out "Hello". But can some one please help to explain why it does it? I am confused because there is no instructions like PUTS. Does it have something to do with loading values to R0? Thank you!

```
     LEA R1, PROMPT
L1   LDR R0, R1, #0
     BRz FOO ; FOO is some other routine
L2   LDI R3, DSR
     BRzp  L2
     STI R0, DDR
     ADD R1, R1, #1
     BR L1
DSR    .FILL xFE04
DDR    .FILL xFE06
PROMPT  .STRINGZ  "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `DSR` is a memory mapped register that shows when the output device is busy (hence the `L2` loop that waits) and `DDR` I guess is the data register (whatever you write there will be output). `R0` gets the characters of the prompt one at a time.

Comment: Aren't DSR and DDR just labels?

Comment: Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017878/where-is-32768-coming-from

Answer (score 1):

DSR and DDR are pointers to the memory locations xFE04 and xFE06 respectively. These are specific memory locations that are built in lc3 software. The one you labeled DSR stands for display "status" register. If the display is not busy, meaning it is ready to print out a single character the value stored in the memory location xFE04 will be a negative value, your loop L2 will run forever until this becomes true. What DDR display "data" register does is it stores your data in the memory location xFE06, which gets your data printed on the screen. They're very similar to KBDR and KBSR.